# Using Factory Method to Create Generics

Tags: java, generics, collections, interface, factory-method

I have an abstract class (Candy) with a generic collection (Flavors). Candy has a factory method to produce concrete instances of itself. It also has methods to get an instance of the generic flavor appropriate to the concrete candy and to add the flavor to its collection.

I know the getter is working, because if I cast the flavor from the CandyStore, the methods unique to the concrete flavor work fine. But the very last line, the addFlavor(flavor), errs (Eclipse) on me. The error is: "The method addFlavor(capture#5-of ? extends IFlavor) in the type ICandy is not applicable for the arguments (IFlavor)." Can anyone explain what is going on?

Interface:

```
public interface ICandy <Flavor extends IFlavor> {
    public Flavor getFlavorForCandy();
    public void addFlavor(Flavor flavor);
}
```

Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class AbstractCandy<Flavor extends IFlavor> implements ICandy<Flavor> {
    public static ICandy<? extends IFlavor> buildCandy(String flavor){
        if(flavor.equals("Jolly Rancher")
            return new JolRanchCandy();
    }
    public Flavor getFlavorForCandy() {
        return (Flavor) new CandyFlavor();
    }
    public void addFlavor(Flavor flavor) {
        ... //implemented
    }
}
```

Concrete Class:

```
public class JolRanchCandy extends AbstractCandy<JolRanchFlavor> {
    ... //implemented
}
```

Used By:

```
public class CandyStore {
    private ICandy<? extends IFlavor> candy;
    private IFlavor flavor;
    public void createCandy() {
        candy = AbstractCandy.buildCandy("Jolly Rancher");
        flavor = candy.getFlavorForCandy(); //returns a JolRanchFlavor
        flavor.setName("Apple");            //etc for creating flavor
        candy.addFlavor(flavor);   //no luck
    }
}
```

Edit: For clarity, `JolRanchFlavor extends CandyFlavor implements IJolRanchFlavor` and `CandyFlavor implements IFlavor`.

Comment: You have declared `ICandy<? extends IFlavor> candy` and this declaration won't allow the addition of any `Flavor` at all. You would be better by declaring it as `ICandy<IFlavor> candy`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The problem with your suggestion is that `addFlavor` takes a concrete instance `Flavor` instead of `IFlavor`.

Comment: @JohnB and the problem with that approach is... Another example, `List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<>(); numbers.add(new Integer(5));` which compiles and runs with no problem.

Comment: But `Number` is an interface of which `Integer` matches. Notice that `addFlavor` takes `Flavor` which is not an interface but the generic type of the class. Such as the `T` in `ICandy <T extends IFlavor>`

Comment: And I guess `JolRanchFlavor` is a class implementing `Flavor` interface or a subclass, so the code would compile as well when you use `ICandy<Flavor>`. Test it yourself.

Comment: Image this, I create a `AbstractCandy<JolRanchFlavor>`. As such `addFlavor` will only accept an instance of `JolRanchFlavor` which makes sense because it should not take a `GoodAndPlentyFlavor`. Now I cast to `AbstractCandy<IFlavor>` so NOW `addFlavor` will take any `IFlavor`. So I now have permission to assign a `GoodAndPlentyFlavor` to a Candy that should have only taken a `JolRanchFlavor`. Oh what an odd world that would be. It makes more sense to say "this is a candy of some T, getFlavor gives me a T, I can pass a T to addFlavor"

Comment: prefixing interface names with `I` is a [terrible practice and shows that there is something wrong with your abstraction.](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2011/02/interface-and-class-naming-anti-patterns-java-naming-convention-tautologies/)

Comment: @JohnB while you're right with your statement, a `CandyStore` won't have `Candy<T>` candies. Ever. Oh what an odd world that would be.

Comment: For clarity, `JolRanchFlavor extends CandyFlavor implements IJolRanchFlavor` and `CandyFlavor implements IFlavor`. Will edit into original post. @JarrodRoberson, I would prefer not to have interfaces at all but my shop requires them for mocking classes, so I try to make the best of it.

Comment: [Same comment from answer below.] Thanks for the responses. Generic typing all the way through works about as well as changing all my `flavor` types to `IFlavor`. The problem with both is that when I then try to downcast `flavor` to `JolRanchFlavor` to use its unique methods, I get, "java.lang.ClassCastException: CandyFlavor incompatible with JolRanchFlavor". (This may warrant a new question?)

Comment: [Same comment from answer below] This is because you need `JolRanchCandy` to override `getFlavorForCandy` to return an instance of `JolRanchFlavor` as the default implementation returns a `CandyFlavor`.

Comment: Can you explain why it returns a `CandyFlavor`? I see it returning the generic `Flavor`, which is `<Flavor extends IFlavor>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
public <T extends IFlavor> void createCandy() {
    ICandy<T> candy= (ICandy<T>) AbstractCandy.buildCandy("Jolly Rancher");
    T flavor= candy.getFlavorForCandy(); 
    flavor.setName("Apple");            
    candy.addFlavor(flavor);  
}
```

The problem is the declaration of `private ICandy<? extends IFlavor> candy`. Since the type of the candy is unknown and therefore `?` the compiler doesn't know exactly what kind of `IFlavor` `addFlavor` should take. You just need to define a generic holder for the `IFlavor` type so that it is preserved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This way works about as well as changing all my flavor types to IFlavor. The problem with both is that when I try to downcast flavor to JolRanchFlavor to use its unique methods, I get, " java.lang.ClassCastException: CandyFlavor incompatible with JolRanchFlavor". (This may warrant a new question?)

Comment: This is because you need `JolRanchCandy` to override `getFlavorForCandy` to return an instance of `JolRanchFlavor` as the default implementation returns a `CandyFlavor`.

Comment: The above begs the question, if this method can ONLY produce a `JolRanchCandy`, then `candy` should be of type `JolRanchCandy`. There is no point in making the method generic if you are then going to say, but wait I know what this is.

Comment: Got it. This was what I was hoping to avoid with generics, because all `Candy`s return a `CandyFlavor` (`IFlavor`) implementation specific to themselves. CandyStore has a hard-coded means of distinguishing what to cast down to (from another system, not one I can control).
Yes, there are many more different `Candy`s, not just the one.